# Apache cxf using XSLTJaxbProvider as a JAXRSDataBinding

Tags: apache, xslt, cxf

(apologies for broken links at stackoverflow limits new users to 2 in one post!)

I've scaffolded a web service server using Spring STS and MyEclipse for spring and was interested in transforming the out going soap message.

First thing I wanted to transform was the namespace prefixing so my spring config looked like this

```
<jaxws:endpoint xmlns:tns="ttps://etc etc">
    <jaxws:dataBinding>
        <ref bean="data-binding"/>
        </jaxws:dataBinding>
</jaxws:endpoint>

<bean ref="data-binding" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding">
        <property name="namespaceMap">
        <map>
            <entry>
                   <key>
                          <value>ttp://thing</value>
                       </key>
                       <value>BeepBeep</value>
            </entry>
            </map>
        </property>
  </bean>
```

this worked fine and my soap message was outputted completely and correctly.

```
<as>
<b>
    <stuff/>
</b>
<c>
    <more stuff/>
</c>
</as>
```

Second I need to change the soap xml but more than the transform features at http://cxf.apache.org/docs/transformationfeature.html allowed

so I read up about the XSLTJaxbProvider at http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-advanced-xml.html and plugging in a rs provider to a ws binding at ttp://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-data-bindings.html#JAX-RSDataBindings-CXFDataBindingsasJAXRSproviders to create the following config

```
<jaxws:endpoint xmlns:tns="ttps://etc etc">
    <jaxws:dataBinding>
         <ref bean="jaxrs-data-binding"/>
    </jaxws:dataBinding>
```

```
<bean id="jaxrs-data-binding" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JAXRSDataBinding">
           <property name="namespaceMap">
       <map>
    <entry>
           <key>
                  <value>ttp://thing</value>
               </key>
               <value>BeepBeep</value>
    </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="provider" ref="xsltProvider"/>
```

```
    <bean id="xsltProvider" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.XSLTJaxbProvider"> 
        <property name="outTemplate" value="classpath:/WEB-INF/templates/transform.xsl"/>
</bean>
```

now I get an JAXB Exception: Class not known to this context for classes b and c and even if I have an empty xslt stylesheet I get the xml

```
<as/>
```

I have tinkered with the config to every end and added  @XmlSeeAlso all over the place to no avail.

I guess I have to ask is what I've done possible in config? The fact that it all works as expected before I try and wire in the rs provider as a ws databinding might mean it's not?

Any advice greatly appreciated. Maybe there is a better way to use xslt/manipulate the xml?

Thanks